# New SSD USB drive: fdisk doesn't change partitions and mkfs doesn't change format

Tags: usb, ext4, ssd, fdisk, mkfs

I have this portable SSD drive that I am trying to format for use with my Raspberry Pi 3: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00N0V4JG2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N0V4JG2)

In the past I have used this exact product, but the 128GB version, formatted as FAT32 on my OSX machine, and the drive worked with no issues on the Pi. I'm using it store the Bitcoin blockchain. Now that the blockchain is too big I'm trying to replace the drive with a 512GB drive, and I am having no luck getting this thing to work!

[I first tried the OSX FAT32 format, but that didn't work.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60394/switching-from-128-to-512gb-usb-storage-drive-makes-computer-unusably-slow/) So I'm trying to format it with the Pi itself.

Starting off with `fdisk /dev/sda` as `sudo su` with USB drive unmounted:

```
/dev/sda1           2 1000215215 1000215214  477G  b W95 FAT32
```

Then I go through the process of [d]elete, [n]ew, [w]rite:

```
/dev/sda1        2048 1000215215 1000213168  477G 83 Linux
```

but even after a `partprobe` AND a reboot, `fdisk -l` still reports no change:

```
/dev/sda1           2 1000215215 1000215214  477G  b W95 FAT32
```

... am I doing anything wrong up to this point? I also went forward with `mfks.ext4 /dev/sda1` and still don't see anything changing (I can post those logs too...) And when I run `fsck` it is a TOTAL BLOODBATH -- which is even more confusing! How can a freshly formatted, brand new file-system have so many errors? Stuff like this (selected examples out of hundreds):

```
Inode 138789 has a extra size (30700) which is invalid 
Inode 138825 has a bad extended attribute block 17929510.
Inode 138877 has compression flag set on filesystem without compression support.
Inode 139153 has a extra size (6956) which is invalid
```

Finally, when I attach the drive my OSX machine I can format it and use it and it works FINE. So I think the drive is not defective.

Comment: Maybe try `parted`?

Comment: Maybe using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=5` to zero out the first 5MB of the device will help? Be **very** sure to check the `of` parameter!

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev same behavior with `parted`. It looks like I am deleting and creating new partitions and filesystems but when I restart `parted` and `print` it shows no change! Do I have a defective drive?

Comment: What about `gdisk` instead of `fdisk`? Your disk may have a hybrid GPT partition table.

Comment: @xhienne Just installed and tried `gdisk`, and again it looks like I'm deleting and writing but on relaunch it only reports a `FAT32` partition. `gdisk` also indicated  `MBR: MBR only /  BSD: not present / APM: not present /  GPT: not present`

Comment: OK, that "MBR only" means that there is no GPT and that `fdisk` is the right tool. The disk seems faulty. Otherwise, I'm afraid you need an exorcist.

Answer (score 0):

out of the top of my head, using parted and vfat fs (assuming you need windows compatibility):

NOTE: assuming /dev/sda is your drive to be formatted (!)

```
parted
(parted) select /dev/sda
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart 
--> pick a name <enter> 
--> pick an fs (ext2 will do) <enter>
0% <enter> 
100% <enter>
print
```

The above should show you you've create a single partition using the full size of the drive. Next we'll create the filesystem:

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
```

Should work. If not let me know, provide output so we can all see what went wrong and try and help you.

Comment: OK I'm having some luck with this but not total success. I think the other tutorials I saw didn't include `mklabel` so I kept reusing the same partition table. Is `gpt` the best option? After running Bitcoin for a several minutes, it started returning tons of database corruption issues again (with an `ext2` format) so I'll try ext4 and maybe even FAT again.

Comment: This was the most helpful comment, so bounty. However I still can not get a large SSD to run smoothly on the pi. I'm on my second brand: https://www.amazon.com/PNY-Elite-480GB-Portable-Solid/dp/B01GQPXB3U/r and I'm going to try a variety of volume formats but so far nothing works as well as the original 128GB drive

Answer (score 0):

[The linked product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N0V4JG2) looks quite suspicious:

- not associated with any known HDD/SSD vendor
- a small business brand
- in the technical specifications, "Hard Drive Interface" says **USB 1.1**(!!!)
- the fact that the partition table seems to reset back to initial state suggests a drive failure

These drives might be salvaged from some major SSD manufacturer's Quality-Assurance rejects bin, originally meant to be scrapped/recycled. Some of them might actually work, at least for a while. Or they might be outright fakes, with custom firmware to hide their actual capacity and flaws, at least until the vendor has managed to get some quick cash.

You might want to check it using the [F3 - Fight Flash Fraud](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tools and/or [flakyflash](https://github.com/whitslack/flakyflash).

Comment: re: USB 1.1 -- this post is over 5 years old